# Visio Timeline Start/Finish Date position

Tags: microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2010

In Visio, I have a timeline that is 2 years long, with intervals every quarter.  The dates for the quarters show immediately below the timeline, but the start and finish dates for the timeline display several lines below that.  Is there any way for the start and finish dates to be on the same line as the interval dates?  I can't find any options for repositioning those dates.

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 0):

Select the timeline shape and open its shapesheet. Scroll down to the **User-defined cells** section and look for the row called **User.visInterimOffset**.
Adjust the formula in this cell to get the height you want. There are other cells in that section that might also be of interest to you.

Comment: It looks like **User.visBEOffset** is more like what I'm looking for, but in either case, it appears I don't know what I'm doing.  Changes made to either row seem to have no effect on the timeline.